# django do I need to open port on ipv6 and ipv4?

Tags: django, web, ipv6, ipv4

I have an application installed on a vps using port 80 which works fine. I just installed a testing application using port 8000 and through the firewall manager opened the port for ipv4.

I can access the application ok, but my client says they get the screen starting to load and then stops.

Is it possible that after the initial url (ipv4) loading other files in the html (css, js) is using ipv6 on their computer? If so why would it work on my PC (Win7) and not on their PC(Mac)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the network configuration of both the VPS and the client, but it is certainly a possibility.